# Notification for user/visitor/customer for incomplete webbased app?

Tags: web-development

I have been developing an in-house small web-based application for my customer and I. The front-end has been only 60% completed, only the main functions without any testing, and the back-end (my private part) hasn't yet been touched as I want to finish the front-end first. The problem is the website needs to be lived within a few day. I need to upload the unfinished not tested version. Should I put small prints/note on the website that this version is a beta or what else should I say to avoid customer's disappointment and notify them upfront. Is it quite unorthodox to do this, should I wait until the front-end is 100% completed?

Comment: Two questions so we can answer this properly: will this webapp work at all if it goes live, or will it be completely unusable? And, why can't you upload it to `localhost` or something similar?

Comment: I'm going to ask the moderators at the programmers SE site if this is on topic for them If so I will migrate this there.